# Sticky Macbook Lid

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) exhibits a lid-opening issue when it has been closed for a while.  It is very difficult to open, to the point where it does not stay put on the desk.  Subsequent close and opens work just fine, until the lid has been closed for a couple of hours.  It is then difficult to open again.

I suspect the rubber spacer around the display is adhering to the body.  The spacer does not feel gummy or sticky.  Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: You probably need new hinges for the display assembly

Comment: @Allan I suppose that is possible, but would that explain the ease of opening after the initial difficult open?